# Laravel 5.4 change the subject of markdown mail

Tags: php, laravel, email, laravel-5.4

I have used [markdown mailables](https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/mail#markdown-mailables) which is a new feature in laravel 5.4. I have successfully implemented a mail sender. It seems, the subject of the mail is named as the name of the `mailable` class. I need to change the subject of the mail and it's hard to find any resources regarding this.

Comment: Please add some code. We know what is markdown mails in laravel.

Comment: This appears to be an issue with the ShouldQueue implementation, i am having the same issue

Answer (score 53):

There is subject method in laravel mailables.

> All of a mailable class' configuration is done in the build method. Within this method, you may call various methods such as from, **subject**, view, and attach to configure the email's presentation and delivery. : https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/mail#writing-mailables

You can achieve this like this :

```
/**
 * Build the message.
 *
 * @return $this
 */
public function build()
{
    return $this->from('example@example.com')
                ->subject('Your Subject')
                ->markdown('emails.orders.shipped');
}
```

You may need to execute `php artisan view:clear` after modifying your class.

Answer (score 4):

If the email subject is the same for all emails then just overload the $subject parameter in your extended Mailable class.

```
/**
 * The subject of the message.
 *
 * @var string
 */
public $subject;
```

Answer (score 0):

## complete code (tested)

```
<?php 
    
    namespace App\Http\Controllers; 
    use Illuminate\Http\Request; 
    
     use Mail; 
    
    class ContactController extends Controller { 
    
         
    
         public function sendContactMail(Request $request) { 
            $this->validate($request, [
                'name' => 'required',
                'email' => 'required|email',
                'subject' => 'required',
                'user_message' => 'required'
            ]);
    
         
    
            Mail::send('contact_email',
                 array(
                     'name' => $request->get('name'),
                     'email' => $request->get('email'),
                     'subject' => $request->get('subject'),
                     'user_message' => $request->get('user_message'),
                 ), function($message) use ($request)
                   {
                      $message->from($request->email );
                      $message->subject("Your Subject");
                      $message->to('email to');
                   });
    
              return back()->with('success', 'Your message was sent successfully');
    
        }
    }
```